# React native : Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation

I'm new to react native. I want to make a project with react navigation. I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at FileStore.get(:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stores\FileStore.js:26:19)
at C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:76:40
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:18:30)
at C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:37:14
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:15:12
at Cache.get (C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro-cache\src\Cache.js:102:7)
at C:\Users\fz\Documents\androidproject\test2\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:166:34
```

This my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from './input.js';
import Kalkulator from './kalkulator.js';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-        
        navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

const RootStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Input: Input,
    Kalkulator: Kalkulator
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",        
  "test": "jest",
  "android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --      
    entry-file index.js --bundle-output 
    android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
    android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "react": "16.6.3",
      "react-native": "0.57.8",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
      "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
      "jest": "23.6.0",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
      "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

I tried to search at google but I can't find the way to fix this, before I built this project I have tried use react navigation in my previous project and it's fine, but why now I get this error?

Comment: The question doesn't contain relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . `FileStore` isn't used anywhere. The error means that there's invalid JSON.

Comment: hi,maybe this is because of some error in modules,try this:
1: delete folder 'node_modules'
2: run `npm install` in terminal in the project directory

Comment: @amirhosein i have tried that, but i still get error like that

Comment: @estus sory if my question doesn't contain relevant code, 
i confused because i didn't passing any data in json format, if i delete import react-navigation there is no error, but when i import react-navigation its will be error like that

Comment: I see. This likely means that cache file became broken for some reason. That's what stack trace says. You can debug said FileStore.get and check what file it refers to. Just modify source file in node_modules and place console.log here and there to know JSON file path, then navigate there and check what's wrong with it. This is a problem with react-native itself, consider opening an issue in a repo (you will need to check what's wrong with that JSON any way).

Comment: i see: fileStore.js 26:19
 there is : `return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(this._getFilePath(key), "utf8"));` 
can you check if it is same on your project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got stuck at the same problem today. I spent hours searching for a solution. Nothing worked. **Finally,** I did something like this:

Try running this command-

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

in your root project directory and this error will be resolved.

The purpose of this command is that it starts the npm after resetting the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth to check if you forgot some ';' at the end of any line.